# Definition of pressure for viscous fluids

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics, viscosity

Hc verma, concepts of Physics, vol 1 pg 258

> We define pressure of fluid at the point A as : $P= F/\Delta S$.
> For a homogeneous and non-viscous fluid, this quantity does not depend on orientation of $\Delta S$ and hence we talk of pressure at a point.

Why did the author stress that the definition holds only for non-viscous fluids?
What happens to viscous fluids? Does the pressure depend on orientation?

Comment: Fill in the blank:  The equation relating the stress tensor to the velocity gradient tensor of a viscous Newtonian fluid is given by .......................................................

Answer (score 1):

Pressure is the only surface force acting in an inviscid fluid. In a viscous fluid, you would also have [viscous stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscous_stress_tensor) (which can be imagined as a friction force between the fluid and the surface). And while pressure is isotropic and doesn't depend on the surface orientation, viscous stress is in general non-isotropic, and it depends on the surface orientation.